# add diagonal reference line to ecdfplot

Tags: r, graphics, lattice, annotate

I have the following call to ecdfplot in the latticeExtra package:

```
ecdfplot(~ saved_multtest + saved_unadjusted + saved_bonferroni + 
    saved_hochberg + saved_independent,
    data=saved, auto.key=list(corner=c(0.8,0.2)),
    main="Null case", xlab="p-value", 
    ylab="Empirical F(p-value)")
```

I would like to add a diagonal reference line, that is, a straight line from (0,0) to (1,1).  I have searched the documentation for quite a while without finding out how to do this, perhaps because I am new at R.  I would be grateful if someone could tell me how.

Comment: Try `abline(0, 1)`

Comment: abline (after the ecdfplot call) does not work.  I get "Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: I was being dumb. See below.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
lines(c(0,1), c(0, 1))
```

lines() lets you specify specific coordinates to join, whereas abline() only lets you specify a slope and intercept.

Comment: Now the error message is "Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet."  I think the diagonal line has to somehow be incorporated into the ecdfplot call, but I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Ahh -- no, that's your issue.  You don't add it to the original call to ecdfplot. You make the figure using ecdfplot, then once that is created the lines() or abline() call will add a line to the existing plot. That should take care of it, hopefully.

Comment: Just to follow-up on that, you see the "plot.new has not been called yet" in both error messages. That means that R is expecting to have an open plot window.  You can create a blank plot with plot(NULL), even, and then create a plot with various calls to lines(), points() , etc.

Comment: I tried running your code -- I too got an error with the ecdf function. But have you tried this way? I didn't get any errors, and the lines() function added the line, as desired:

    x <- runif(1000);
    plot(ecdf(x));
    lines(c(0,1), c(0,1))

So, this uses the base R ecdf function, which has an associated plot method.

Comment: The problem is that `latticeExtra::ecdfplot` uses `grid` graphics which are not compatible with standard R graphics functions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `lattice` (why???) then this will do what you want:

```
ecdfplot(rnorm(1000), panel = function (x, y) {
  panel.ecdfplot(x)
  panel.abline(0, 1)
})
```

Customize to taste.